# How to make scrollbar can scroll in UITextView in iOS?

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

I have a lot of huge text to show in `UITextView`.

My case is i want to scroll `UITextView's` `scrollbar` with touch.

In `UITextView` , i can only scroll with original scroll feature.

I want to scroll UITextView with scrollbar that exist in right side of UITextView like browser but i can't scroll it.

In Mac , we can scroll with scrollBar like that.

[image]

How can i do it?Is there any Custom controls for my requirement?

Comment: I dont think,you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Hope it will help you.